# Requiring first_name and last_name in Django User model

Tags: python, django, database, authentication, model

In `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, both `first_name` and `last_name` fields have `blank=True`. How can I make them `blank=False, null=False` in my own model?

Here is my implementation, which basically follows the instructions of [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model):

> models.py

```
class Fellow(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(
        _("first_name"),
        max_length=30,
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        _("last_name"),
        max_length=30,
    )

    # other fields omitted

from . import signals
```

> signals.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Fellow


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_fellow_on_user_create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Fellow.objects.create(user=instance)
```

However, I got an error when testing in `python manage.py shell`:

```
>>> f = Fellow.objects.create(username='username', password='passwd')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 392, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 571, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'username' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: You should derive your model from the original User class.

Comment: @KlausD. You mean subclassing `User` directly? But the example code from the documentation writes `class Employee(models.Model):` instead of `class Employee(User): `...

Comment: @KlausD. Doing this gives me an error: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'first_name' in class 'Fellow' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'User'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood the tutorial. The employee example you are referring to explains how to add to the `User` this is done by way of a `OneToOneField` that leaves the original `User` model intact but for all practical purposes it's as if the `User` had a new field called `department`. This is implemented by creating two separate tables in the database.

There is one caveat, in the `Employee` and the `Fellow` you can't directly create new instances in the way you have tried without first creating a `User` instance. That's because neither of those models directly own a username field. So do it in two steps

```
user = User(username='Sun')   
user.set_password('123')
user.save()

f = Fellow(user=user)
```

But this approach is still less than desirable. you have a first_name and last_name field in both models. It will always lead to confusion. The proper method is to subclass AbstractBaseUser

```
class Fellow(AbstractBaseUser):

   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
```

`AbstractBaseUser` is a bare bones User (see the code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L47) it does not have a first_name and last_name so you can add them with the behaviour that you want.

Answer (score 0):

The very first line of documentation you are referring to says

> There are two ways to extend the default User model without substituting your own model

The keyword is **without substituting**

I see 3 options here:

1) Derive you User class from [AbstractBaseUser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c651331b34b7c3841c126959e6e52879bc6f0834/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py) and define all required fields. You can take [AbstractUser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c651331b34b7c3841c126959e6e52879bc6f0834/django/contrib/auth/models.py) as an example.

2) Add validation either to UserSerializer or to `pre_save` signal on user save model and validate `first_name` and `last_name` fields. The simplest way, but not a good option for a long term project.

3) Do the way you've chosen by adding a reference to a `User` model as a `user`. Define `first_name` and `last_name` but ensure than there is no duplication of those fields between `Fellow.first_name` and `Fellow.user.first_name`. This could be hard as other developers may misunderstood the idea.
An error you get happens because User model has not been created and the right way to initiate a `Fellow` instance would be:

```
user = User.objects.create(username='test', email='test@example.com')
fellow = Fellow.objects.create(user=user, first_name='firstname', last_name='last_name')
```