# Creating profile model on instance creation

Tags: python, django, database, authentication, signals

According to [Extending the existing User model¶](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

> These profile models are not special in any way - they are just Django
>   models that happen to have a one-to-one link with a user model. As
>   such, they aren’t auto created when a user is created, but a
>   `django.db.models.signals.post_save` could be used to create or update
>   related models as appropriate.

But how can I use `post_save` to pass the necessary arguments to `MyCustomeModel.objects.create`? Taking the example of the official document:

> models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)

from . import signals
```

> signals.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Employee


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_fellow_on_user_create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Employee.objects.create(user=instance, **kwargs)
```

An error happened when I tried to create a user by `User.objects.create(username='username1', password='passwd')`

> TypeError: 'signal' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

when using `Employee.objects.create(username='username1', password='passwd')`, a similar error happened:

> TypeError: 'username' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Here is the full stacktraces:

```
(django_tutorial) sunqingyaos-MacBook-Air:fellow_go sunqingyao$ python manage.py shellPython 3.6.1 (default, Mar 23 2017, 16:49:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from pickup.models import Employee
>>> User.objects.create(username='username1', password='passwd')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 80, in save
    super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 806, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 846, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 193, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 193, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/PycharmProjects/fellow_go/pickup/signals.py", line 12, in create_fellow_on_user_create
    Fellow.objects.create(user=instance, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 392, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 571, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'signal' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
>>> Employee.objects.create(username='username1', password='passwd')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 392, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/sunqingyao/Envs/django_tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 571, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'username' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
>>>
```

Comment: @e4c5 Edited question. That was my bad: I thought full stacktraces are too long to be included in the question, and a one liner is enough to state my problem.

Comment: The one about Employee is the one I have already answered in your previous question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Requiring first\_name and last\_name in Django User model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43949131/requiring-first-name-and-last-name-in-django-user-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Signals this way!

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_fellow_on_user_create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Employee.objects.create(user=instance, **kwargs)
```

The first issue here is that according to the [method signature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save) the first three arguments in **kwargs will be `raw`, `using` and `update_fields`. They don't exactly correspond to what your Model requires.

The second issue is that when you listen to signals, the process isn't always in your control. There is no assurance that the reciever will ever get data for all the fields that you want.

The bottom line issue though, is your misunderstanding of the manner in which the `User` model is to be extended. The solution to that is given in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: If I understood your previous answer correctly, `Employee.objects.create(user=instance)` is enough?

Comment: I had just copy pased your code to say 'cant use this way'. You are not going to have the required data in **kwargs

Comment: yes, now your comment makes sense. But that still depends on what exactly you have in your Employee model. As per your previous question, you current employee model is wrong. So this isn't going to work either. As mentioned, the solution to your problem is not in this question and answer but in the previous one

Comment: Yeah, according to your enlightening answer, I have to subclass `AbstractBaseUser` in this case. Does that mean I don't need to deal with Signals anymore? BTW, subclass `AbstractBaseUser` seems more convenient and flexible than adding a `OneToOneField`, so that's the purpose of doing the later?

Comment: Well it's mostly a matter of choice. For most apps the built in `User` is fine. So people create another model with a OneToOneField to add things like profile pictures, postal addresses etc

Comment: Last question: do I need to reimplement the manager by subclassing `BaseUserManager`? All I want is mandatory `first_name` and `last_name`

Comment: Doesn't look like it. But you will probably want to use a custom signup form https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views